# What are some good reference books for signals?

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis, laplace-transform, book-recommendation, fast-fourier-transform

The title might be a bit misleading, but basically I've been self studying differential equations so I could apply them in electronic circuit design. I was wondering what books could be recommended on differential equations, the Fourier, Laplace, and Z transforms, PDEs up to solving the wave equation, convolutions, filtering, and both discrete and continuous approaches to signal processing. One book that's caught my eye was *Differential Equations: A Modern Approach with Wavelets* by Steven Krantz, but I'm not sure how relevant wavelets are in modern signal processing. But regardless, if there are any books you've enjoyed a lot, please let me know!

Also, if possible, I was wondering what a good book on information and coding theory would be, specifically with a focus on communications?

I just want some physical reference books on these topics I'm learning by other means, since holding physical books is different from using an ebook. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @Moo, I've actually been going through Oppenheim's "Signals & Systems." I was just looking for other books I could look into, maybe some DSP books or ones with more of a focus on differential equations.